# Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903 and Windows update files

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-installation

In **Windows Update**, I clicked **Check for updates**

And I see, **You’re up to date**

Also, I see

*The Windows 10 May 2019 Update is on its way. We're offering this update to compatible devices, but your device isn't quite ready for it. Once your device is ready, you'll see the update available on this page. There's nothing you need to do at this time.*

I purchased my laptop for about 1 month ago. It came with Windows 10 Home Single Language, version 1803.

Its specification is Processor: Intel Core i5-8250U Processor, GPU: AMD Radeon 540 2GB GDDR5, HD: 1TB and RAM: 12 GB DDR4.

I couldn’t understand my laptop will take further updates of Windows 10 version or not.

I discussed the issue on another platform and I found it’s alternatives as

- I should wait until Microsoft fixes the incompatibility issue between my computer hardware and Windows 10 feature update. Or
- I can update using Windows Update Advisor.

I agree with both options.

When I use **Windows Update Advisor**, it detected Windows 10 1903. It means, my laptop's Windows 10 can be updated to the next version (1903).

Now the confusion is...

1. Should I update using **Windows Update Advisor** or should I wait until Microsoft fixes incompatibility issue?

Moreover,

In case of Windows update to next version, first of all, update files get downloaded in the computer, then the installation process starts. If an interruption occurs during installations or installation failed, most probably it goes back to the previous state.

1. How do I know, where update files downloaded in the computer?
2. If interruption or failure occurs, will all required files be downloaded again in the next attempt or installation process will start from the same file that was downloaded previously?
3. If interruption or failure occurs, it goes back to the previous state. In such scenarios, Windows works normally as previous but may I expect any issue or bug in Windows because of interruption or failure?

Comment: At this time, it's safe to update to Windows 10 v. 1809 (from 1803). There are still some issues with v. 1903, so unless you want to help MS by replacing QA, then you'd best wait.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Most of the issues with 1903 have already been resolved.  There are actually unresolved issues with virtually [every version of Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903).  Most issues affect multiple versions of Windows 10.  However, I won't disagree, that the 1903 specific issues are indeed a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I update using Windows Update Advisor or should I wait until Microsoft fixes incompatibility issue?

Your machine is currently not compatible with Windows 10 version 1903.  You are going to have to wait until Microsoft resolves the incompatibility from the list of issues that will block the upgrade to Windows 10 1903.

A dynamic list of known issues with Windows 10 version 1903 can be found [here](Windows 10, version 1903 and Windows Server, version 1903).  Any issue that has the statement "**to safeguard your update experience**" will prevent the Windows 10 version 1903 from being installed on your system.

Some of those issues have been resolved, but since the dynamic list is several pages long, it wouldn't be helpful to quote any specific issue at this time.  Any issue that indicates the issue was resolved, if it was previously an issue that would block the upgrade, should contain the statement "**safeguard hold has been removed.**"

Source: [Windows 10, version 1903 and Windows Server, version 1903](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903)

> How do I know, where update files will be located?

It is not necessary to know the location of these files.  Windows will download the required files to a hidden directory.  You can use the Disk Cleanup tool to delete them.

> If interruption or failure occurs, will all required files be downloaded again in next attempt or installation process will start from the same file that was downloaded previously?

If you attempt the upgrade, and the process is rollback for any reason, the entire process has to be repeated.  This means you should clear out the temporary file before you attempt the upgrade again.

> If interruption or failure occurs, it goes back to the previous state. In such scenarios, Windows works normally as previous but may I expect any issue or bug in Windows because of interruption or failure?

The Windows installation is rolled back to the previous state.  I have encountered numerous Windows installation problems in the fast installing feature updates.  However, I notice absolutely no problems with those installations, after the installation was rolledback[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1452836/is-it-safe-to-update-to-1903-even-if-my-computer-says-its-not-ready/1452838#1452838)

The most likely reason the upgrade to Windows 10 1903 is blocked on your system is due to the [Windows 10 1903 upgrade failure resulting from an attached USB device issue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/resolved-issues-windows-10-1903).  While the issue should not block the upgrade to 1903, it is very likely, your system does not have the most recent Windows 10 version 1803 cumulative update installed.  **This particular issue affected both external removable mass storage devices but also internal HDDs.**

> If Windows10Update folder (of size about 6GB) is the downloaded files, I didn’t understand, why this drive (E:) was selected randomly for saving update files?

Windows has a habit of picking the largest location to store temporary files.

> I believe there will not be an issue if I uninstall Windows 10 Update Advisor program from appwiz.cpl and delete both folders of Windows10Update.

You should use the Disk Cleanup tool instead.

> After going through some views and articles, now I don’t want to go for re-attempt for Windows update through Windows 10 Update Advisor. That’s why I want to diagnose if any issue occurred because of installation failed and want to delete downloaded files.

If you run Disk Cleanup and select to remove the installation files the upgrade will not be attempted.

> I don’t know it was my mistake or not but I started downloading updates through Windows 10 Advisor. Once the download process is done, the computer restarted and Installing Windows 10 started.

The Upgrade Assistant (which is also known as the Windows 10 Advisor) only attempts the upgrade.  It is assumed that if you are using the assistant you want to attempt the upgrade, even if there are compatbility issues, with the feature update.  However, some issues will still block the installation, but those checks are not performed until later in the process.

Comment: @user886982 - Just because it was detected doesn’t mean it’s compatible